# How can i integrate joomla media selector into a custom component

Tags: joomla

I'm writing a custom component for joomla 1.5 and i been searching for a way to integrate 
com_media image selector into it.

All  i want, is to have a functionality like, the image selection in the create article page.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Is there an API in joomla to do this, or do i have to see how is done in com_content an start
form there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select box with image preview like the one used for the Sections and Categories thumbnails. This is much easier to integrate though images must come from single directory.

See the `com_sections` and `com_content` files in you Joomla Administrators components directory.

Also try posting this in the Joomla Forums.